# How to declare char array as function parameter ?or tell me there is some other thing wrong in this code?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

What should I do to resolve this ?

i don't know any other way so i didn't try anything

```
bool isPresent(int p_rows,int p_cols,char p_search[p_cols'1']'2','3'char p_words[][p_cols])
```

The counting in single commas indicate which error I m receiving at which point.
One more thing which I would like to mention is that I m doing recursion in this program and there are other functions also whose parameters are same as of this but only this function definition is causing errors

```
1)use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
2)expected ')' before ',' token`enter code here`
3)[Error] expected unqualified-id before 'char'
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<char>` instead of dumb arrays.  Then you don't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature. However in this declaration

```
bool isPresent(int p_rows,int p_cols,char p_search[p_cols], char p_words[][p_cols]);
                                                   ^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^
```

you are trying to use variable arrays declarations.

For the last parameter declaration

```
char p_words[][p_cols]
```

the variable `p_cols` must be a compile-time constant.

The declaration can look the following way. I suppose that the array passed to the function as the last argument is declared in a program like an array with fixed constant dimensions and the variables `p_rows` and `p_cols` specify a sub-array of the array.

```
bool isPresent(int p_rows,int p_cols,char p_search[], char p_words[][N]);
```

where `N` is the second constant dimension of the original array.

For example

```
const size_t M = 100;
const size_t N = 100;

bool isPresent(int p_rows,int p_cols,char p_search[], char p_words[][N]);

int main()
{
    char p_words[M][N];
    char p_search[N];

    // ...    

    int p_rows = 10; 
    int p_cols = N;

    isPresent( p_rows, p_cols, p_search, p_words );

    //...
}
```

Otherwise you should use for example `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`, or `std::vector<std::string>`, or an array of `std::vector<char>`, or an array of `std::string` instead of your original array definition.

Answer (score 0):

declaring a character array as an argument is the same as declaring it as a variable.

for example, the array

```
char ch_array[SIZE];
```

can be declared as an argument for `foo` like that

```
void foo(char ch_array_arg[SIZE])
```

it can also be declared as a pointer to a sequences of characters as in

```
void foo(char *ch_array_arg);
```

of course in that example you will also have to specify the size of the array.

Comment: There is no array being used in the function declaration.  It is no different than `void foo(char *ch_array_arg);`  Thus the two functions are exactly the same thing.